# jQuery selector (selects all instead of .parents)

Tags: jquery, selector

I'm having a small problem with a jQuery selector and after trying myself for a while I decided I needed some help with this.

```
$('.submenu').on('click','.groen',function() {
    $(this).parents('#content_vragen').find('.container_vragen').fadeOut(400, function() {
        $(this).parents('#content_vragen').find('.container_vragen').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        $(this).parents('#content_vragen').find('.container_vragen').appendTo("#geregeld");
        $(this).parents('#geregeld').find('.container_vragen').css('color', 'green');
        $(this).parents('#geregeld').find('.container_vragen').fadeIn(400);
    });
});
```

I have a class called .submenu, inside that .submenu is a < p> element with the class "groen". The .submenu element is inside a div with the class "container_vragen". Which is a container id called "#content_vragen".

```
<div id="content_vragen">

    <div class="container_vragen">
        <div class="submenu">
            <p class="groen">groen</p> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container_vragen">
        <div class="submenu">
            <p class="groen">groen</p> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container_vragen">
        <div class="submenu">
            <p class="groen">groen</p> 
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

So my fairly easy question is: how can I do an action only on the .container_vragen class in which the class .groen is clicked. I thought I had to select the parent of this (the .groen button) and work it back to the .container_vragen, but this way it selects all the .container_vragen elements. Just to make things a bit easier here's a jsFiddle of the whole project: http://jsfiddle.net/86Hcc/

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.closest` -- that will get the closest parent with the given selector:

```
$(this).closest('.container_vragen');
```